# Axios not sending cookie data, even with withCredentials:true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Trying to make requests and send cookies along with it using React and Express. The requests/responses are working fine. But the cookies are not sent. On the client-side:

```
import axios from 'axios'

let endPoint = 'http://192.168.1.135:80'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export async function SubmitPost(username, title, body, time){
    let res = await axios.post(`${endPoint}/posts/create`, {username: username, title: title, body: body, time: time})
    return res.data
}
```

The server-side route:

```
router.post('/create', authenticator.authenticate, async (req, res) => {

    let post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        body: req.body.body,
        time: req.body.time,
        username: req.body.username
    })

    post.save().then((doc, err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(Response('failure', 'Error occured while posting', doc))
        }

        res.send(Response('success', 'Posted Successfully'))
    })
})
```

And the middleware authenticator:

```
module.exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

    if (token == null) {
        console.log('No authentication token found')
        return res.sendStatus(401)
    }

    jtoken.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.sendStatus(403)
        }

        req.user = user
        next()
    })
}
```

It returns a 401 with a Token Not Found. I have enabled CORS on express as well as cookie-parser

```
app.use(cookieparser())
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/authentication_route'))
app.use('/posts', require('./routes/post_route'))
```

Comment: Authorization headers with tokens and cookies are two different things. What should be looking at is something like the following - https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults

Comment: @goto1 I see, but any reason the cookies are not being sent?

Comment: This will depends on how your cookies are set up - if they're `SameSite` cookies and you're doing a cross site request then perhaps that could be an issue.

Comment: @goto1 Have tried setting it to strict and to none, but didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

[image] Late to this party, but not setting the SameSite cookie option can be an issue. The image above is from Chrome's network console.