# Postman POST works, but not with axis

Tags: javascript, axios, postman, insomnia

Making a post request via insomnia/postman works, gives me the correct response.  However, in axios, I can't seem to make it work.

It doesn't give me an error, its a status 200, but doesn't actually login like postman/insomnia does. I feel something is wrong with my axios setup

[image]

[image]

```
  const { email, password } = req.body.params
  const endpoint = `https://xxxxxxxxx.com/account/login/`

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: endpoint,
      data: qs.stringify({
        'customer[email]': email,
        'customer[password]': password,
        'form_type': 'customer_login'
      }),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    res.status(200).send(response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error)
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to stringify the data, I don't know, if that's really the issue tho. Reference: https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api. Also your endpoint in the code is different than the one in postman.

Comment: I've tried without stringy the data, and same result =/

Comment: What about the endpoint? Your endpoint in the code has far more `x`s than the one inside postman

Comment: Ah thats just an example : )

Comment: In Postman click the code icon on the top right and change the code snippet format to "NodeJS - Axios" and it should generate the code to recreate the exact same query you performed in Postman in Axios. More information here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions (I hope) :

1/ Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744593/axios-not-sending-cookie-data-even-with-withcredentialstrue), you should probably use `withCredentials` like this :

```
  const { email, password } = req.body.params
  const endpoint = `https://xxxxxxxxx.com/account/login/`

  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  try {
      (...)
  }
```

2/ Following [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/), you need to set your Content-Type header to application/json so the data is automatically parsed :

> Axios also sets the Content-Type header to application/json. This enables web frameworks to automatically parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Postman lets you generate the code necessary to recreate your request using axios.

More information on that here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Click the code icon to the right of Postman

[image: Postman code button]

Then set the code snippet language to `NodeJS - Axios` and you'll have the exact code necessary to recreate the request.
[image: Axios code snippet]